# How to directly copy value from attribute table associated with a selected feature?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes

I need to copy the attribute value (only one particular attribute) of a selected point and save it in a text file. Is there any Python script or plugin which can do this for me? I need to save a lot of points so individually copying the values is going to be tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to save values from one particular field, you could use something like the following in the **Python Console**:

```
def save(fieldName):
    result_path = 'path/to/file.txt'
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    result = ''
    for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
        result += str(feat[fieldName]) + '\n'
    with open(result_path, 'a') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

Then select your features and type `save('myField')` to run the function (note the single quotes around the field name).

---

Personally, I would also include the ***id*** of the feature so that it can be matched to the attribute. So if you wanted, you could replace:

```
result += str(feat[fieldName]) + '\n'
```

with

```
result += str(feat.id()) + ': ' + str(feat[fieldName]) + '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this keeps giving me errors. It says error in syntax at lines 1, 3 and 5 and 6 randomly. Found out what was wrong.

Comment: @SunnyNaik - Did you set the path of the text file and the field name correctly?

Comment: Yes, the file is getting created. But there is nothing stored in it.

Comment: @SunnyNaik - I cannot replicate your issue, it's working fine for me. Are you sure selected your features **before** running the code?

Comment: Yes I selected the features, only one time it got saved, the rest of the times it did not.

Comment: @SunnyNaik - Edited my post which wraps the code into a function. Hopefully this will work for you and is much easier to use instead of constantly typing out lines of code :)